# Get rows from a table with a Range Column

Tags: java, guava

If I have a large Guava Table Like this:

```
Table<Foo, Range<Long>, Bar> myTable;
```

And I have a long value, and a Foo object -  i want to get the Bar object that has a Range containing my long.

Right now, the best I can do to get all Bar with a Foo key in the Range i need is this:

```
Map<Range<Long>, Bar> row = cache.row(myFoo);
for (Range<Long> range : row.keySet()) {
            if (range.contains(myLong))  {
                return Arrays.asList(sample.get(myLong));
            }
        }
```

As you can see, i'm grabbing the row from the table, and iterating through the ranges looking for my one Bar with a closed range that contains myLong.

Is there a better way to find my object without the for loop? Getting a RangeMap from that column of Ranges in a way faster than that loop perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map<Foo, RangeMap<Long, Bar>>` sounds like it'd be perfectly appropriate here.  It won't be quite as nice an API as `Table`, but it's the only way to perform that operation in less than linear time.

Comment: Thanks Louis, this looks like an answer to my question.